# Characterizing Coprimes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Here's a question about coprimes that I stumbled upon while doing some research. Providing insight into this question would prove quite helpful to me.

Choose a pair of coprimes $x, y \in \mathbb Z$. What constraints have to be placed on $x$ and $y$ for the following pair of equations to have integral solutions?

$$ax + by = 1$$ 
$$a + b = 0$$

The first equation can be solved from the assumption that $(x, y) = 1$. It is not obvious to me when the second constraint can be satisfied, if ever.

I've restated the problem a bit using insights from Bézout's identity and the equations describing the general structure of Bézout coefficients.

First, let $k$ be the difference bewteen $x$ and $y$ so that $k = x - y$. $y$ can then be expressed in terms of $x$ with the identity $y = x - k$. The equations can then be restated:

$$ax + b(x-k) = 1$$ 
$$a + b = 0$$

The coefficients $a$ and $b$ which satisfy the first equation are not unique. If the Bézout coefficients (a, b) provide a solution to the equation

$$ax + b(x-k) = 1$$

then for any $m \in \mathbb Z$, the following coefficients also provide a solution:

$$(a + m(x-k),\; b - mx)$$

The constraint that $a + b = 0$ can be generalized to all coefficients:

$$(a + m(x-k)) + (b - mx) = 0 \implies$$
$$a + mx - mk + b - mx = 0 \implies$$
$$a + b - mk = 0 \implies$$
$$a + b \;|\; k$$

Substituting $x - y$ for $k$ we then require

$$a + b \;|\; x - y$$

or

$$ a + b \equiv 0 \;\;\;mod\;\; x - y$$

Now the problem can be restated in terms of division. For coprimes $x$ and $y$, when can Bézout coefficients be found satisfying $a + b \;|\; x - y$, where

$$ax + by = 1$$

Said another way, what constraints must be places on coprimes $x$ and $y$ so that they posess a pair of Bézout coefficients whose sum divides their difference?

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\ b = -a\,\Rightarrow\, 1 = ax\!+\!by = a(x\!-\!y)\ \ $

Comment: Er $a+b=0\iff a=-b$, so that all divisors of $a$ are divisors of $b$, but then they're only coprime if one of them is $1$ and the other is $-1$.

Comment: It seems like the key fact I overlooked is that $ax + by = 1$ implies that both $(x, y) = 1$ and $(a, b) = 1$. So restating your insight, if $a = -b$, then $(a, b) = 1$ iff $(a, b) = (1, -1)$ or $(a, b) = (-1, 1)$. x and y would both need to be either 1 or -1. Am I correct?  

Adam, feel free to write it up as an answer.

Comment: If I replaced the constraint $a + b = 0$ with $a + b = m(x - y)$, does this pair of equations have a non-trivial solution set?

$$ax + by = 1$$
$$a + b = m(x-y)$$